# Passing jQuery objects to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/fjtFA/2/embedded/result/) of what I want to achieve.  Just enter some value in input and you might get what I want to achieve. (Yes, I got it working but stay on..)
But it fails when multiple keys are pressed together.

What I am trying :
 I have screen which contains few enabled and few disabled input elements. Whenever user updates any value in editable  input element, I want to update disabled input which had same value with user updated value.

HTML :

```
<input value="foo" />   // When User updates this
<br/>
<input value="bar">
<br/>
<input value="Hello">
<br/>
<input value="World">
<br/>
<input value="foo" disabled>  // this should be updated
<br/>
<input value="bar" disabled>
<br/>
<input value="foo" disabled>  // and this also
<br/>
<input value="bar" disabled>
<br/>
<input value="Happy Ending!">
<br/>
```

I tried this which I think will save me from multiple_clicks_at_a_time
JS:

```
$(":input:not(:disabled)").keyup(function () {
    // Get user entered value
    var val = this.value;

    // Find associated inputs which should be updated with new value
    siblings = $(this).data("siblings");
    $(siblings).each(function () {
         // Update each input with new value 
         this.value = val;
    });
});

$(function () {
    $(":input:not(:disabled)").each(function () {
        // Find inputs which should be updated with this change in this input
        siblings = $(":input:disabled[value=" + this.value + "]");

        //  add them to data attribute   
        $(this).data("siblings", siblings);
    });
});
```

But I am not able to pass the selectors to `keyup` function and invoke `.each` on it.

---

**PS:**

My previous completely different try, working with single_click_at_a_time but I felt that I am unnecessarily traversing the DOM again and again so dropped this

```
$(":input").keypress(function () {
    $(this).data("oldVal", this.value);
});

$(":input").keyup(function () {
    var oldVal = $(this).data("oldVal");
    $(this).data("newVal", this.value);
    var newVal = $(this).data("newVal");

    $("input:disabled").each(function () {
        if (this.value == oldVal) this.value = newVal;
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you storing the siblings with `.data()` instead of selecting them when you're actually ready to use them? And why are you re-jQueryifying them in the `keyup` callback?

Comment: Why are you binding the `keyup` event outside of the DOMready function?

Comment: @Bergi probably because all of this code is running on window load in the fiddle. Not that that's an excuse...

Comment: @MattBall: Because in `keyup` I wont have old input value so thought its better to find the required input with required values on page load itself.

Comment: @Bergi: Not much into jQuery, I used to keep *all custom functions* outside the `document.ready` so just followed my bad habits..My bad

Comment: You really should think about using some kind of data-binding framework like `knockoutjs` for this. It'll make it so much easier.

Comment: Knockoutjs will be easier only if you already know knockoutjs. Otherwise expect to be unproductive for a week - minimum.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Agree. Wont for it out. Not because its good/bad but just because I am a java guy and it seems hell lot difficult to me.

Comment: Indeed Karna, there's nothing in your question that should require knockout. jQuery should do everything very nicely. No point making things more complicated than they have to be. Mr Burland will disagree of course but he's made the investment of time in learning knockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Find associated inputs which should be updated with new value
siblings = $(this).data("siblings", siblings);
```

No. The [`.data` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) called with two arguments does not get, but set the data (and returns the current selection). Also, you should make your variables local:

```
var siblings = $(this).data("siblings");
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjtFA/12/)

Comment: Oops, my copy paste blunder. Was not working with that also http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/fjtFA/10/. Still +1 for pointing it out

Comment: cant we store jQuery objects (may be in data) and retrieve them and call any function on them like `.each`?

Comment: You can. See my working demo. In your version 10 fiddle you somehow stored the `siblings` value on the `siblings`' data properties.

Comment: Exactly what I trying. But if I try the same code in my way like defining it outside the DOM it doesnt work. What diff exactly it make if I dont define it as callback?

Comment: In v13 you did forgot the dot right before `keyup()`, check your error console for the syntax error. Btw, `:input:disabled[value=Happy Ending!]"` is no valid selector, leading to unexpected behaviour - better use an exact [filter function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 2):

I would group those inputs first and bind a handler for enabled elements to apply to the group. See below,

```
var grpInp = {};

$(":input").each(function () {
    if (grpInp.hasOwnProperty(this.value)) {
        grpInp[this.value] = grpInp[this.value].add($(this));
    } else {
        grpInp[this.value] = $(this); 
    }
});

$.each(grpInp, function (i, el) {    
    el.filter(':enabled').keyup(function () {
        el.val(this.value);
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/fjtFA/9/

The above approach basically groups input element with same value, then filters them based on `:enabled` and bind a handler to apply it to the group.

Comment: Oh gosh.Short and sweet but I just dont understand it. Will be great if you can add some light on it.

Comment: Group all input elements by `value`. After that first `.each` The `grpInp` object will look like `{foo: [input1, input4, input6], ...}` in which `input1` is the first element with value `foo`, `input4` is the fourth input element which has value `foo`. So basically it groups down input by value. The second iterate is used to iterate by group and bind a keyup handler to the **enabled** elements in the group. The handler simply updates the value to all elements in the group.

Comment: A lot better than mine. But will accept Bergis answer he points out my mistake and gave answer in my way. Thanks a lot though..